# Surface Integral of vector field bounded by two spheres .

Tags: surface-integrals, divergence-theorem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS6Tz.png)

A vector field :
$$D\mapsto \mathbf{a}_r\frac{\cos^2\phi}{r^3}+\mathbf{a}_\theta\sin\theta$$
Exists in the region between two spherical shells defined by r=1 cm and r=2 cm .
Evaluate : 1) Plot the field lines inside the mentioned region

2. the closed surface integral $\oint D\cdot ds$
3. the divergence theorem $\iiint \nabla\cdot DdV$

please help me to solve it , I can solve it using divergence theorem but I don't no how can I solve it by the closed surface integral $\oint D\cdot ds$

Comment: Please, don't use pictures for critical portions of your posts.

Comment: a) what have you tried? b) are the vectors $a_r$ and $a_\theta$ the unit vectors in spherical coordinates?

Comment: See also: [Q4863263_Field_Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CuEe.png)